# Connecting to WCF service using AJAX in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to connect to simple `wcf` service locally, but every time I get some errors. 
This is my `WCF` :

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    public int square(int number)
    {
        var res = number * number;
        return res;
    }

}
```

And this is `AJAX` part :

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:9247/Service1.svc/square',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json ;charset=utf-8',
                data: { number: number },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#Result').val(data.d.res);

                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
```

What's wrong ? Can anybody explain me ?

Comment: "every time I get some errors"   Errrr, it might help us, if you tell us *what* error messages you're seeing...?

Comment: Object {readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. hope its helpfull for you

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/calling-wcf-services-using-jquery/